# Following code input comes out undefined error

Tags: javascript, var

Hi I'm new to coding and currently working with `var`, when I put the code always returns `"undefine"` I can't tell what I'm doing wrong does anyone knows? The code is as follows:

```js
function greetings() 
{
  var myFriend = "Jeff"; 
  var greetings = "Welcome back, " + myFriend + "!" 
}

// leave this line unchanged to console log the results
console.log('results: ', greetings());

// don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined')
{ 
  module.exports = greetings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to return a value, add the `return` keyword on the last line.

```js
function greetings() {
  var myFriend = "Jeff";
  var greetings = "Welcome back, " + myFriend + "!" 
  
  /* You should add the following line. */
  return greetings;
}

console.log('results: ', greetings());

// Don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = greetings;
}
```

Comment: no wonder, I wouldnt get the code thank you

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted to say.